# Angular2 - turn 'activatedRoute.params' into promise

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, angular-promise, observable

I am trying to turn the observable for params that I get off of the `ActivatedRoute` into a promise but haven't had any luck.  I have been able to turn `http` requests into promises successfully:

```
this.riaService.getAdvisorsForState(this.activeState)
    .then(rias => {
        this.riasForState = rias.json();
        console.log(this.riasForState);
    });
// this all works ^
```

But I have not been able to turn the 'activatedRoute.params' into a promise:

```
export class InvestmentAdvisorStateComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private riaService: InvestmentAdvisorService) { }

    getStateFromUrl() {
        this.activatedRoute.params
            .toPromise()
            .then(params => {
                console.log('HERE',params)
            });
    }
// this does not work for me ^
```

This is what I have right now:

```
getStateFromUrl() {
    this.activatedRoute.params
        .subscribe((param: any) => {
            this.activeState = param['state'];
        });
}
// works ^
```

I am hoping to implement this as a promise thought so I can `.then` off of it.  Any help on how to do this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What behavior do you expect? This promise probably only completes when you navigate away from that route while `http.get()` completes when the response from the server arrives.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Oh, I didnt realize that.  I edited my post to show the functionality that I have right now with `.subscribe`.  I am trying to turn my observable into a promise so I can chain it with `.then`

Comment: Why not just with `.map()`

Comment: hmm.. that didnt allow me to turn it into a promise

Comment: If you turn it into a promise, you defeat the purpose of using the "live" route. You might as well just use the snapshot.

Comment: Why do you need a promise. Leabe it as observable and use `.map()`. There is nothing a promise can do that an observable can't. What exactly are you trxing to accomplish.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I am trying to chain multiple promises together, I believe I can do that for an observable with `flatmap`, but I just prefer promises

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The main difference between observable and promise is, that observable can emit multiple events while a promise only emits a single event.

To make your example work, I assume you are only interested in the first event.

```
getStateFromUrl() {
    this.activatedRoute.params
        .first()
        .toPromise()
        .then(params => {
            console.log('HERE',params)
        });
}
```

This way the promise created with `toPromise()` is completed with the first `params` event.

Comment: awesome anwser. I add that to get more sync-looking-like code you can use `public async ngOnInit() { let params = await this.activatedRoute.params.first().toPromise();
console.log('pppp', params); }`

Comment: I had to use `await this.route.params.pipe(first()).toPromise();` - any idea why?

Comment: If you have code that follows above code then this is normal async execution behavior. If all code is inside `then(...)` you don't need `await`.